# Map from $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^6$ is Immersion for...

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, matrices, manifolds

$$\phi :\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^6$$
$$(u,v,w)\rightarrow \phi(u,v,w)=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)$$

where $ \quad x_1=u^2 \quad x_2=v^2 \quad x_3=w^2 \quad x_4=vw \quad x_5=uw \quad x_2=uv$

For the Jacobian Matrix I get the following: 
 \begin{pmatrix}
        2u & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2v & 0  \\
        0 & 0 & 2w  \\
        0 & w & v \\
        w & 0 & u \\
        v & u & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}

I am looking for subsets $\Omega \subset R^3 \; $ so that $\; \phi$ is an Immersion. Additionally, what are the largest convex subset for which $\phi$ is an Immersion. For which convex subsets is $\phi$ injective and $\phi^{-1}$ continous ?

$\phi \; $ is clearly $C^{\infty}\;$ and the Rank of the Jacobian Matrix is 3 for any open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3-(0,0,0)$. An open convex subset would be $\mathbb R_+^3:=\{(x,y,z): x,y,z>0 \}$
Am I  right ? If so can someone give me a hint on how to find a convex subset for which $\phi \;$ is injective ? Is $\phi^{-1}\;$continous for any of those subsets ?

Comment: Regarding injectivity, have you tried to analyze conditions under which $\phi(u_{1}, v_{1}, w_{1}) = \phi(u_{2}, v_{2}, w_{2})$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hmm,  if $u,v,w \;$ are all negative or positive then looking at the first 3 equations you would get $u_1^2=u_2^2$ and so on. Hence $\phi$ is injective. Am I right ?

Comment: Yes, but you can say even more, e.g., $\phi$ is injective on the open half-space $u > 0$ (by looking at the first coordinate alone).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oh right. So the largest open subsets for which $\; \phi $ is injective would be the half open space $u>0$ or $ v>0$ or $w>0$.

Comment: Those sets certainly "work", and are easily seen to be maximal convex sets not containing the origin. They're not the only such sets, however: Similar arguments (which you've pretty much got) show $\phi$ is injective on every open half-space omitting the origin. :)